# No display of the app directory in the plugin file_picker

Tags: android, dart, plugins, directory

Why do I only see the media folder under the Android directory in the **file_picker** plugin.
I even have the **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission. Still, I don't see any other folders.
I was able to display the folder structure in another app that had the same rights. And that wasn't a system app.
I would need access to the app folder, because files from the app are saved there that I want to read again when necessary.
Can someone give me a tip on how I can do that.

Comment: What do you consider to be the app folder? Pleasebtell full path.

Comment: I need the path from the download folder (/download) and the app folder (/Android/data/myApp/)

Comment: You should tell full paths. Second time i ask.